# How to display video in full screen mode using ExoPlayer?

Tags: android, fullscreen, exoplayer, exoplayer2.x

I am using Customised ExoPlayer to display videos in my project. I set some fixed height for ExoPlayer view let say 300dp the video is playing without any issues. But the problem is if I set the height of ExoPlayer view to match parent and change the screen orientation to landscape the video is playing but it keeps on buffering. The state of the video most of the time is reaming in the buffering state. Please help me to solve the issue and I am posting the code snippet of my data source below.

```
public void play(String url) {
    defaultBandwidthMeter = new DefaultBandwidthMeter();
    TrackSelection.Factory trackSelectionFactory = new AdaptiveTrackSelection.Factory(defaultBandwidthMeter);
    exoPlayer = ExoPlayerFactory.newSimpleInstance(new DefaultRenderersFactory(VideoNewFullScreenMode.this),
            new DefaultTrackSelector(trackSelectionFactory), new DefaultLoadControl());
    MediaSource datasource = buildMediaStore(url);
    exoPlayer.prepare(datasource, true, true);
    simpleExoPlayer.setPlayer(exoPlayer);
    exoPlayer.setPlayWhenReady(true);
    simpleExoPlayer.setResizeMode(AspectRatioFrameLayout.RESIZE_MODE_ZOOM);
    exoPlayer.seekTo(getIntent().getLongExtra("position", 0));
    //updateTimers();
    exoPlayer.addListener(this);
}
private MediaSource buildMediaStore(String mediaUrl) {
    Uri videoUri = Uri.parse(mediaUrl);
    DataSource.Factory dataSourceFactory = new DefaultHttpDataSourceFactory(Util.getUserAgent(this, getApplicationInfo().packageName), defaultBandwidthMeter);
    DefaultExtractorsFactory extractorFactory = new DefaultExtractorsFactory();

    return new ExtractorMediaSource(videoUri, dataSourceFactory, extractorFactory, null, null);
}
```